# Option Sets intersections in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, optionsettype

Now I read Apple documentation about Core Text and I have one problem in understanding:

[`CTFontSymbolicTraits`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coretext/ctfontsymbolictraits)
conforms to `OptionSet`. And [`CTFontStylisticClass`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coretext/ctfontstylisticclass) can be obtained via `classMaskTrait` option in `CTFontStylisticClass`.

Am I understand right that `classMaskTrait` option can includes all `CTFontStylisticClass`-options?. For example, if I want to detect `sansSerifClass` option in `CTFontStylisticClass`:

```
CTFontStylisticClass(rawValue: CTFontGetSymbolicTraits(font).rawValue).contains(.sansSerifClass)
```

is it right example checking?

Comment: Before we go answering this, may we think about whether Core Text is needed for what you are really trying to do? What _are_ we really trying to do? This looks like something we could do much more easily with a font descriptor and never have to drop down to the level of Core Text. What is `font` and what question about it are you actually trying to answer?

Comment: I want to detect stylistic qualities of the font

Answer (score 0):

To understand these constants, let's look at the [`CTFontStylisticClass` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coretext/ctfontstylisticclass?language=objc#):

> The class values are bundled in the upper four bits of the `CTFontSymbolicTraits` and can be obtained via `kCTFontClassMaskTrait`.

To verify, let's look at the [`kCTFontClassMaskTrait` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coretext/ctfontsymbolictraits/kctfontclassmasktrait?language=objc). If you set the language to Objective-C, the documentation shows the definitions of `kCTFontClassMaskTrait`:

> ```
> kCTFontClassMaskTrait = kCTFontTraitClassMask
> ```

So it's just defined as another constant, which has all the same words in a different order. Ha ha, Apple, you're hilarious.

Okay, let's look at the [`kCTFontTraitClassMask` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coretext/ctfontsymbolictraits/kctfonttraitclassmask?language=occ). Again, if you set the language to Objective-C, you can see the definition of the constant:

> ```
> kCTFontTraitClassMask = (15U << kCTFontClassMaskShift)
> ```

Indeed, `15U` is four consecutive 1 bits, and it's shifted left by some amount. This is typical of a “mask”: it defines a subset of the bits in a binary word.

To convert a `CTFontSymbolicTraits` to a `CTFontStylisticClass`, we need to use the mask to select just those bits from the `CTFontSymbolicTraits` raw value, and use the result as the raw value of a `CTFontStylisticClass`. We can do the selection by using the bitwise operator `&`, or by using the `OptionSet` method `intersection`.

What we really want, in Swift, is a method on `CTFontSymbolicTraits` that extracts a `CTFontStylisticClass`. So let's write an extension:

```
extension CTFontSymbolicTraits {
    var stylisticClass: CTFontStylisticClass {
        return CTFontStylisticClass(rawValue: self.intersection(.classMaskTrait).rawValue)
    }
}
```

Let's test it:

```
import CoreText
import Foundation

extension CTFontSymbolicTraits {
    var stylisticClass: CTFontStylisticClass {
        return CTFontStylisticClass(rawValue: self.intersection(.classMaskTrait).rawValue)
    }
}

func checkSansSerifness(fontName: String) {
    let font = CTFontCreateWithName(fontName as CFString, 12, nil)
    let fullName = CTFontCopyName(font, kCTFontFullNameKey)!
    if CTFontGetSymbolicTraits(font).stylisticClass.contains(.sansSerifClass) {
        print("\(fullName) is sans serif.")
    } else {
        print("\(fullName) is not sans serif.")
    }
}

checkSansSerifness(fontName: "Helvetica")
checkSansSerifness(fontName: "Times New Roman")
```

Output:

```
Helvetica is sans serif.
Times New Roman is not sans serif.
```